# JavaScript String to Array and add boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add `true` after splitting string into array:

```
var str = "California,Nevada";
var array = value.split(',');
this.setState({ value: array });
console.log(this.state.value)
// result is ["California", "Nevada"]
```

I needed result like this:

```
{California: true, Nevada: true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
var str = "California,Nevada";
var result = {};
str.split(',').forEach(function(e){
  result[e] = true;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array#map function along with `split` to create the new object

```js
var newObj = {};
var str = "California,Nevada".split(',').map(function(item) {
  newObj[item] = true;
});
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you wanna do is creating a new object and then iterate over the splitted input like this:

```js
const input = "California,Nevada";
const output = {};
input.split(',').forEach( item => output[ item ] = true );
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to split `str` and not `value` in the second line, you can do something like below.

```js
var str = "California,Nevada";
var array = str.split(',');

// I think you need to use this.state instead of state
var state = {}; 
array.forEach(item => state[item]=true);
console.log(state)
```